# Reading the contents of excel file

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am using JDBC to read an excel file which is in table format.

I was quite successful in doing that. But, one of my coulmns has **`link`** to external file sources. I was able to get, the name of link, on using jdbc

Is there anyway to get the href value of link through JDBC ?

I can make use of APache POI, but it is huge maintenance issue for me

Comment: can u share some code ?